# Prevent SSH from logging out after running initial commands

Tags: 14.04, command-line, ssh, automation

I'm using `ssh` to connect to a remote Linux machine like this:

```
ssh -i .ssh/path/to/id_rsa -p 22 user@host 'cd /path/to/dir'
```

I'd like some commands to be executed upfront (such as `cd /path/to/dir`) and then proceed with my own business, but I get logged out right away after the commands are run. Any way to stay logged in?

Comment: Not a duplicate. `cd /path/to/dir` is just an example. I've got more than just one command to execute.

Comment: In that case, please [edit] and clarify. However, since you have cross-posted this on U&L, please leave this one closed and edit the one there instead.

Comment: @terdon I'm deleting the one on U&L

Comment: As you wish but since this one is closed... Anyway, please clarify how many commands you need to run. The simplest approach would probably be to add them to a script and call that script from your `.profile` on the remote server.

Comment: @terdon About three commands. I'd rather not split scripting logic across two machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify your shell afterwards so that runs. You also need the `-t` flag for a proper shell experience. So you end up with something like:

```
ssh ... -t user@host 'cd /path/to/dir; /bin/bash'
```

As terdon suggests in the comments, if you have a big stack of commands that you want to run *every* time you connect to this server as *this user*, you probably want to edit your `.profile` or `.bashrc` to run the commands automatically.

Comment: It works but `user@host` prompt is missing..

Comment: Yeah, just remembered (finding a question of mine) that you need to throw in the -t flag.